# pass data from command to the service

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to pass some data from one page's code-behind to the service, when I click a button on which I bind a command.
So lets say in the example.xaml page I have a button with a command, and on the example.xaml.cs I have some data which I want to pass along with the command.
 Is this possible?
here is my view :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.Pages.MapPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.ViewModel"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.Classes;assembly=HelloWorld">
  <Button Command="{Binding GetInfo}"
            Text="Hello World"/>
```

here is my code behind

```
 Models.Data data;
    public MapPage(List<Models.Info> info, Models.Data data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.data = data;

        //i want to pass this parameter to the service
          var somedata = "John doe";
    }
```

this is the view model which is called when I click the button

```
public ICommand GetInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                Info = await _apiServices.GetInfosAsync();
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MapPage(Data, info));
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is the service page:

```
public async Task<List<Info>> GetInfosAsync()
    {
           //  ==i would like to use the data in here, the var some data ==
           var keyvalues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TheData", somedata),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MoreData", "example"),
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
       "http:someurl/");
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyvalues);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

The json is ok and it returns some information when I hard code the data in the key-values pair but I Would not like to hardcode the data. 
So this is pretty much my code. Is it possible to pass data on button click?? Thank in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course you can pass data to a service.  The specifics will depend on how your service is written and what sorts of parameters it expects.  It's hared to tell exactly what you're trying to do - your code doesn't appear to be valid.  Please read up on MVCE in the help sections.

Comment: @Jason I edited my question, I would appreciate it if you could take a look on it.

Comment: you would just add whatever variable you want to pass in place of the somedata or "example" placeholders.  The variables would either need to be class level, or passed into GetInfoAsync() as arguments.

Comment: Yes, I know that... The thing is how do I pass this `somedata` from the `example.xaml.cs` to the `GetInfoAsync` in the viewmodel? @Jason

Comment: create a property on the VM and set it in the code behind

Comment: Thanks Jason, already solved it :) @jason